# How to load more content to item using grid (Bootstrap and jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create html&css layout which contains items in rows and each item clicked will load more content. Something like on this screen:

Grid desktop view:

[image: Grid desktop view]

It would be quite easy to me if not mobile view, which seems that had to have different html elements order:

Mobile view:

[image: Mobile view]

For now I created this html code (using Bootstrap css):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4 item">
            <a class="link" href="#emp_more_4" data-id="4">    
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 emp_info" id="emp_more_4" style="display: none;">
            <div class="emp_info_con">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 module">
            <a class="link" href="#emp_more_3" data-id="3">    
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 emp_info" id="emp_more_3" style="display: none;">
            <div class="emp_info_con">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 module">
            <a class="link" href="#emp_more_2" data-id="2">    
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 emp_info" id="emp_more_2" style="display: none;">
            <div class="emp_info_con">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4 module">
            <a class="link" href="#emp_more_1" data-id="1">    
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 emp_info" id="emp_more_1" style="display: none;">
            <div class="emp_info_con">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where each "emp_info" elements are those with more item's content.

And jQuery code:

```
        jQuery('.employees a').click(function() {
            var id = jQuery(this).data("id");
            jQuery('.employees .emp_info').hide();
            jQuery('.employees #emp_more_'+id).show();
        });
```

It loads more content to each item but it breaks columns and rows layout.
Do You have any idea how to keep grid layout on both desktop and mobile view?
I'm open to style it without Bootstrap classes if someone would have good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Heres a solution that can help you:

Please have a review on code:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.item a', function() {
 $(".emp_info").width($('.row').width() - 30);
  $('.item').attr('style', '');
  $(this).closest('.item').css('margin-bottom', $(this).next().height());
    $('.emp_info').not($(this).next()).slideUp();
  $(this).next().slideToggle(function(){ 
    if($(this).is(':hidden')){
          $('.item').attr('style', '');
      }
  });
});
$(window).on('resize', function(){
   $(".emp_info").width($('.row').width() - 30);
});
```

```css
.item a {
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
}

.item:nth-child(2) .emp_info {
  background-color: #ff0;
}

.item:nth-child(3) .emp_info {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.emp_info {
  background-color: #f00;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
}

.col-lg-1,
.col-lg-10,
.col-lg-11,
.col-lg-12,
.col-lg-2,
.col-lg-3,
.col-lg-4,
.col-lg-5,
.col-lg-6,
.col-lg-7,
.col-lg-8,
.col-lg-9,
.col-md-1,
.col-md-10,
.col-md-11,
.col-md-12,
.col-md-2,
.col-md-3,
.col-md-4,
.col-md-5,
.col-md-6,
.col-md-7,
.col-md-8,
.col-md-9,
.col-sm-1,
.col-sm-10,
.col-sm-11,
.col-sm-12,
.col-sm-2,
.col-sm-3,
.col-sm-4,
.col-sm-5,
.col-sm-6,
.col-sm-7,
.col-sm-8,
.col-sm-9,
.col-xs-1,
.col-xs-10,
.col-xs-11,
.col-xs-12,
.col-xs-2,
.col-xs-3,
.col-xs-4,
.col-xs-5,
.col-xs-6,
.col-xs-7,
.col-xs-8,
.col-xs-9 {
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-4 item">
      <a class="link" href="#emp_more_4" data-id="1">
      </a>
      <div class="emp_info">
        <div class="emp_info_con">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 item">
      <a class="link" href="#emp_more_4" data-id="2">
      </a>
      <div class="emp_info">
        <div class="emp_info_con">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 item">
      <a class="link" href="#emp_more_4" data-id="3">
      </a>
      <div class="emp_info">
        <div class="emp_info_con">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-4 item">
      <a class="link" href="#" data-id="4">
      </a>
      <div class="emp_info">
        <div class="emp_info_con">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 item">
      <a class="link" href="#" data-id="5">
      </a>
      <div class="emp_info">
        <div class="emp_info_con">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! It works almost as I've intended. One issue: I need second and third column more element starting from row left side:
http://i.imgur.com/SLBWA2F.jpg
Is it possible in your solution?

Comment: And second issue is that if window is resized, loaded container doesnt changed width...

Comment: Hi Tomasz. I have fixed in post the resize issue. You can check it but about your first issue what you mean exact about second and third columns?